# Monitoring on OSGi/Equinox

Tags: java, osgi, monitoring, jmx

We are using Equinox as runtime for our app. The OSGi modularity is great, but there's one thing I miss from the JBoss days: the monitoring facilities. JMX is the standard for monitoring in the JVM but Equinox doesn't seem to provide much built-in support for it.

Besides the Equinox [Resource Monitoring](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/incubator/monitoring/) project, which seems to be stale since 2007 (and didn't move out of incubation), what are the options?

What are other OSGi/Equinox adopters using for monitoring OSGi-based applications?  What about other OSGi implementations? This is important enough to trigger a migration in case e.g. Felix+Karaf would offer better monitoring support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options available. [Gemini Management](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/management/) provides an implementation of an OSGi Standard for JMX monitoring of frameworks.

If you'd like to monitor the Servlet environment that you need to look at the options provided by the Servlet engine. We include Jetty in [Gyrex](http://www.eclipse.org/gyrex/) and it provides a couple of options. We also added a few more JMX beans to measure the average request time, information about the last error and more.

Implementing your own JMX beans is actually not difficult. You can call `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().registerMBean(...)` from anywhere in your code to register the beans. Have a look at [our service tracker implementation](http://git.eclipse.org/c/gyrex/gyrex-platform.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.gyrex.monitoring/src/org/eclipse/gyrex/monitoring/internal/MetricSetTracker.java) which registers an JMX monitoring bean for every registered service object of a particular type.

Comment: +1 great. This is what I've been looking for. Do yo have support for whiteboard registration of "manageable" services? I'd like to expose some parts of my services for JMX management (queue size, exec time, used thread count, etc...). Would be nice to have some marker itf (e.g. Manageable) and have a service register those to the MBean server. Maybe reusing your service tracker impl and making it apply to more that `MetricSet` ?

Comment: It's EPL. Feel free to re-use the service tracker implementation. It's also easy to start from scratch. Just create a "monitor" bundle with a service tracker (or an DS component) that tracks all your services and registers MyServiceMBeans for them. I used DynamicMBean but you could also use a "static" MBean if you know your services very well. The "MetricSet" objects we have a dynamic collections of metrics.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using Apache Karaf. You can use it with Felix or Equinox. It provides a lot of monitoring features. Just start up karaf and connect with Jconsole. Besides JMX it has the Felix Webconsole and a great command line that can also be used via ssh.

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread when googling for equinox + JMX. Since this thread is from 2012 and others may come around this in the future its time to add another solution which fitted well for me.

You could easily use [Aries JMX](http://aries.apache.org/modules/jmx.html). Below you can find a wrap up from Aries documentation. To do so add

- A simple Bundle

  ```
  import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
  import javax.management.MBeanServer;
  import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
  import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

  public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
      public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
          MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
          context.registerService(MBeanServer.class.getName(), mbs, null);
      }

      public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {}
      }
  }
  ```
- [Aries JMX Bundle](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.aries.jmx%7Corg.apache.aries.jmx%7C1.1.5%7Cbundle)
- [Aries JMX API Bundle](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.aries.jmx%7Corg.apache.aries.jmx.api%7C1.1.5%7Cbundle)
- [Aries Util Bundle](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.aries%7Corg.apache.aries.util%7C1.1.1%7Cbundle)

as a result it is possible to access the Equinox Container via e.g. JConsole.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Felix Web Console is a pretty powerful tool for monitoring the state of your OSGi container. It can also be run within Equinox.

See http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.html

Comment: How would you instrument your application sothat it can be managed from this console? That's the kind of thing I'm interested in.

Comment: Just include the webconsole bundle (and its dependencies) in your OSGi environment. The link above describes all the deployment/installation details.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear: This webconsole lets you monitor your OSGi runtime (bundles, configuration). I want to monitor my application. Let's say I've an execution queue and I want to monitor its length in production. In javaEE you'd do this kind of things with JMX, but JMX support seems lacking in OSGi, so what are the options?

Comment: PS: I'm quite familiar with the management of the OSGi environment. In Equinox I use the CLI console, which although rudementary, let's you do what the webconsole can do (and is easier to reach in cloud  deployment - you know, ops love CLI :-) )

Comment: Although core OSGi doesn't include JMX, there is an enterprise OSGi standard for JMX, and most of the enterprise OSGi servers include OSGi support.